# Как разделить список на 2 списка(в 1 списке данные str, в другом int)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список

```py
li = ['cow', '1', 'cat', '2', 'dog', '3']
```

В списке `li` все данные `str`.
Нужно разделить этот список на 2 других списка.
1 список будет выглядеть так(в нем все данные типа `str`):

```py
animals = ['cow', 'cat', 'dog']
```

2список так(в нем все данные типа `int`):

```py
num = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def split_animals_and_num(data):
    animals = []
    num = []
    for i in data:
        try:
            num.append(int(i))
        except ValueError:
            animals.append(i)
    return (animals, num)


li = ['cow', '1', 'cat', '2', 'dog', '3']
animals, num = split_animals_and_num(li)
```

Comment: Не лучше ли вместо исключений использовать `str.isnumeric()`

Comment: @vitidev, а разница большая для такой задачи?

Comment: @VOLK использовать исключения, когда есть встроенный метод. Какой бы мелкой не была задача, учите норм. А если у Вас там баг будет? Попробуете отладить?

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю еще вариант решения

```py
li = ['cow', '1', 'cat', '2', 'dog', '3']
animals = []
num = []
for i in li:
    num.append(i) if i.isnumeric() else animals.append(i)
```